# RoR User Management application with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am new to RoR and MongoDB, planning to develop a User Authentication module on RoR with Mongo DB, would like to know what and all gems required for this.
assistance or help links highly appreciated.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Devise gem for user auth and mongoid gem for document mapping to mongoDB. They are f with each other compatible with each other